# Updating from Ubuntu 13.04 to 14.10 with no XP

Tags: upgrade, system-installation, 64-bit

I want to update my incredibly trustworthy Ubuntu 13.04 , I have never had a problem with it even though its unsupported. Its on 64 processor,OS type is also 64 bit.

the problem is, my old XP has died with one of those missing corrupt files `\windows\32\config\system` - messages and I cant find my old CD set up disk.

How do I update to a 13.10 to get to a 14.10 when I cant download to a an XP to install.

I would rather just do a complete new install that would wipe everything of my computer if that’s possible.

I have another computer I could download to a disk and then install on mine.

I have tried heaps of downloads on this one but seem to get to the 50% mark and it stops downloading.

Comment: What's windows XP have to do with upgrading Ubuntu? You can download & burn/write an iso in Ubuntu

Comment: If you download the Ubuntu iso from the terminal using `wget -c` then the wget program will automatically resume a broken download from the same place it was interrupted and **continue** until the download is 100% finished. I've compared the download speed of wget to a torrent, and it's also faster than downloading the Ubuntu iso using a torrent.

Answer (score 1):

you can do fresh installation by downloading the ISO from other computer(since you are having problem downloading on present computer).

or you can do upgrade right from 13.10. for this you will need good internet connection. [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/110477/how-do-i-upgrade-to-a-newer-version-of-ubuntu) on **How do I upgrade to a newer version of Ubuntu?**

Comment: ,@julka , @edwardtorvalds   Many thanks for the time you took to answer my question , between the 3 answers I received I was able to work through the download .

Answer (score 0):

Try Ubuntu Desktop or network installer from Bittorrent http://www.ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads